# Pytorch stuck at moving model to mps

Tags: pytorch, apple-silicon

When attempting to move a Pytorch model to mps, I have encountered a problem where the execution gets stuck indefinitely at the line `model.to('mps')`.

I have attempted to restart my device and reinstall Pytorch (nightly version) to resolve the issue, but to no avail. I have run the exact same code before without any problem, so I doubt it is a implementation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue playing with SatbaleLM on my M1 Max

Using the nightly build of pytorch 2.1.0.dev20230523 fixed my issue, can now pass `'mps:0'` or `'mps'`

I installed with below after removing old version with pip3
`pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu`